# I am looking for a seventeenth century word for a 'shill'

Tags: etymology

A 'shill' is a con artist's accomplice.  I have seen your discussion on the etymology of this word which is likely to be early twentieth century, but I need an earlier word for a story I am writing set in the early 1600s

Comment: *Shill* is short for *shillaber*. As you rightly say it is twentieth-century and mainly North American. The OED knows nothing about its etymology. And there are no examples prior to 1913. Can't help you with the 17th century I'm afraid.

Comment: What is the specific con? And how is the accomplice involved?

Comment: "acolyte" may fit, but doesn't specifically refers to crook's support.

Comment: The con is simple at the moment - the accomplices win some money on three card monte to draw in other players who can then be fleeced!

Answer (score 4):

Knowing only the time period, but neither the swindle nor the role of the accomplice in it, this answer may be overbroad. However, further research should allow you to pick out the word most appropriate for your story.

One word for a swindler's accomplice, now obsolete, attested from 1526 to 1633 in the specific sense shown, is 'stale':

> **stale**, *n.*<sup>3</sup>
>   **†3.** A person who acts as a decoy; esp. the accomplice of a thief or sharper. *Obs.*
>
> ["stale, n.3". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188795 (accessed October 15, 2016).]

Note that 'sharper', meaning a "cheat, swindler, rogue; one who lives by his wits and by taking advantage of the simplicity of others; *esp.* a fraudulent gamester" (*OED Online*), is not attested in that sense until 1681; it is used in the definition of 'stale' in the *OED* not because it was contemporaneous with stale, but because it retains that sense ("cheat, swindler, rogue") to this day.

'Stale' was used with a number of competing senses during the early 1600s, and so may not be the best term for your use.

Another common term for a swindler's accomplice, in use during the early 1600s, is 'barnard':

> **†ˈbarnard**, *n.*
>   The member of a gang of swindlers who acts as a decoy; a lurking scoundrel, a sharper.
>
> [ "† ˈbarnard, n.". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/15629 (accessed October 15, 2016).]

Attested from around 1555 to 1608, 'barnard' did not express the variety of senses enjoyed by 'stale', and so was probably not as widespread in use; it does have the advantage over 'stale' of not having been used in senses competing with "swindler's accomplice".

A third term, perhaps employed with the sense of "swindler's accomplice" was 'barnacle'. *OED Online* is indefinite about the use with the precise sense, as indicated by "perhaps" in definition **3.b**:

> **barnacle**, *n.*<sup>2</sup>
>   **3. a.** *fig.* A companion or follower that sticks close, and will not be dismissed; a constant attendant.
>   **†b.** Perhaps in this sense used as the cant term for a decoy swindler: see quots., and cf. 'barnard' *n.*
>   ....
>   1608   T. Dekker *Belman of London* sig. F3,   He that..before counterfetted the dronken Bernard is now sober and called the Barnacle.
>
> ["barnacle, n.2". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/15624 (accessed October 15, 2016).]

Attestations for this sense of 'barnacle' are given only from 1591 and 1608.

The seeming implication of the quote from 1608 is that the decoy feigning drunkenness was called a 'barnard' or the variant 'bernard', while the sober decoy was called a 'barnacle'. For more nuanced sense, see the 1591 quote given for 'setter' in the following.

Yet another name for a swindler's accomplice used in the early 1600s is 'setter':

> **setter**, *n.*<sup>1</sup>
>   **7. a.** A confederate of sharpers or swindlers, employed as a decoy; also (? with transferred notion of sense 11), one who is employed by robbers or murderers to spy upon their intended victims.
>
> 1591   R. Greene *Notable Discouery of Coosenage* f. 1,   There bee requisite effectually to act the Art of Conny-catching three seuerall parties: the Setter, the Verser, and the Barnackle. The nature of the setter is to draw in any person familiarly to drinke with him [etc.].
>
> ["setter, n.1". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176848 (accessed October 15, 2016).]

In this sense, 'setter' is attested from the 1591 quote shown to 1755. It is not yet obsolete. Sense 11, as mentioned in the definition, is general use with reference to "dog trained to ‘set’ game" (*OED Online*).

Also of interest, another name for a swindler's accomplice in use in the early 1600s was 'tumbler':

> **tumbler**, *n.*
>   **2. †b**. *transf.* applied to a person; *spec.* one who allures or inveigles persons into the hands of swindlers (*slang*). *Obs.*
>
> ["tumbler, n.". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/207355 (accessed October 15, 2016).]

The sense from which **2.b** is transferred, as for sense 11 of 'setter', refers to the use of dogs for a similar purpose:

> **2. a.** A dog like a small greyhound, formerly used to catch rabbits; a lurcher.
>
> (op. cit.)

In the obsolete sense **2.b**, 'tumbler' is attested from 1602 to 1785.

Note that rabbits caught by the tumbler dog in that era, as well as this, are sometimes called 'coneys'; thieves and swindlers generally were commonly called 'coneycatchers' and sometimes 'cozeners'.

Finally, the obsolete slang name 'circling boy', attested only in 1631, was used as the name of a thieves's accomplice:

> **†3. circling boy**  *n.* ‘a species of *roarer*; one who in some way drew a man into a snare, to cheat or rob him’ (Nares). *Obs. slang.*
>
> ["ˈcircling, adj.". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/33196 (accessed October 15, 2016).]

---

Of particular interest to anybody doing thorough research for a story involving thieves and swindlers in the early 1600s, the 1923 edition of Robert Greene's 1591 [*A Notable Discovery of Coosnage*](https://archive.org/stream/notablediscovery00greeuoft#page/n7/mode/2up), which details the practices of the rogues of that era, presents the original in a somewhat more readable form for modern readers. The frontispiece illustration of the 1591 printing summarizes the topic of the work:

[image: illustration: a notable discovery of coosnage]

Answer (score 3):

The word you must be looking for is **cozener**. It's usage can be traced back to late 16th century.

The aggregated list of definitions, etymology and usage is here - http://www.finedictionary.com/cozen.html

Here's the etymology - Just Google "cozen etymology"

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! We strive to provide objective and well-researched answers. If you expand and provide evidence, like a link to an online dictinary, this could become a great answer! Take the [Tour] and see [answer] for more.

Comment: Seconded. Currently this is flagged as "Low quality", which is a bit harsh, but almost certainly due to starting with "I guess..." Don't guess. Be bold! And corroboration is *always* helpful.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - Thanks! Edited the answer accordingly with the required proof